# How to make two vertical aligned components which are not related?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to recreate a simple layout in Reactstrap. I need two vertical columns in which I'll be inject components based on condition. The data from left and right column are not related. I need layout in which I'll inject component on the left, and only there, and vice versa. So it looks something like this:
[image]

I've tried many different variations.

Maybe I'm wrong but I think I need two vertical rows in which they will be columns, but I really do not know how to make this work - every time I try this, component is injected on the left, and next component is injected on the right.
Any help (Reactstrap or plain React components - doesn't matter) will be appreciated.

This doesn't work:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>col</Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>col</Col>
          </Row>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included any CSS included.

Comment: I did not write any custom css, I'm using standard Home.module.css file, with no changes yet

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this website ( https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ ). It'll help you set up the columns in the way you've described.

Answer (score 0):

OK after hours I think I've manage to create this layout in plain HTML/CSS, I'll post this code because it's simple to convert it to React:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>left element</h2>
                </div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>right element</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>right element</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
display: flex;
}

.column {
flex: 50%;
}
```

[image]